# How can make this GStreamer Application perform RTSP Video Stream properly?

Tags: gstreamer

This Gstreamer works great using gst-launch-1.0 command script to self-hosted rtsp service on port 80.

`gst-launch-1.0 -qtme rtspclientsink name=s location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:80/live/test libcamerasrc ! queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! capsfilter caps='video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=NV12,framerate=60/1,interlace-mode=progressive,colorimetry=bt709' ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls='controls,repeat_sequence_header=1,h264_profile=1,h264_level=11,video_bitrate=5000000,h264_i_frame_period=30,h264_minimum_qp_value=10' ! 'video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,level=(string)4' ! queue ! s.`

How to make this GStreamer Application perform the same output (after compiling)?

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  g_print("RTSPClientSink Test has started!\n\n");

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (NULL, NULL);

 pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("-qmte rtspclientsink name=s location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:80/live/test libcamerasrc ! queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! capsfilter caps='video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=NV12,framerate=60/1,interlace-mode=(string)progressive,colorimetry=bt709' ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls='controls,repeat_sequence_header=1,h264_profile=1,h264_level=11,video_bitrate=5000000,h264_i_frame_period=30,h264_minimum_qp_value=10' ! 'video/x-h264,level=(string)4,stream-format=byte-stream' ! queue ! s. ", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  //gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  //return 0;

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  //return 0;

  //msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_STATE_NULL | GST_STATE_NULL);
  //return 0;
  
  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
  gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

The GStreamer Application above will produce an error message.

`(ljc1272060r:8969): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 21:43:46.327: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed`

And so, with the above if remove the single quote at "! video/x-h264,level=(string)4,stream-format=byte-stream !" will allow this GStreamer Application to run and it appears this is running, but there is no video output.

And so, also tried this in the pipeline, gives appearance of running, but there is no video output.

> pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("-qmte rtspclientsink name=s location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:80/live/test libcamerasrc ! queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! capsfilter caps='video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=NV12,framerate=60/1,interlace-mode=(string)progressive,colorimetry=bt709' ! v4l2h264enc extra-controls='controls,repeat_sequence_header=1,h264_profile=1,h264_level=11,video_bitrate=5000000,h264_i_frame_period=30,h264_minimum_qp_value=10' ! capsfilter caps='video/x-h264,level=(string)4,stream-format=byte-stream' ! queue ! s. ", NULL);

Interesting NOTES:

With gst-launch-1.0 script method, the Output Video Stream matches the specified size 720p and format=NV12.

> INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 1280x720-NV12

Whereas the GStreamer Application method, the Output Video Stream does not match the pipepline specified 720p and format=NV12, instead it is attempting run as 1080p and format=NV21, so thus no output stream (I think).

> INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 1280x1080-NV21

Any advice or suggestions?

Thank you,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Suggest updating the string passed to `gst_parse_launch`:

1. Remove -qtme
2. Replace `capsfilter caps='X'` with just unquoted `X`
3. No single quotes around the url

I ran this through your program and it works. I'm not a linux machine, so replaced with ~equivalent x264 encoder config:

```
const char *pipeline_string =
"videotestsrc ! \
video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=NV12,framerate=60/1,interlace-mode=progressive,colorimetry=bt709 ! \
queue2 max-size-buffers=1 ! \
x264enc bitrate=5000 key-int-max=30 qp-min=10 ! \
video/x-h264,profile=(string)constrained-baseline,width=1280,height=720,stream-format=(string)byte-stream ! \
rtspclientsink name=s protocols=tcp location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:80/live/test ";
```